# get operation return data for BinaryJedis when key does not exist

Tags: redis, jedis

I was going through BinaryJedis and BinaryJedisCluster documentation [here](https://static.javadoc.io/redis.clients/jedis/2.9.0/index.html?redis/clients/jedis/BinaryJedis.html). For `get` operation the description says

"Get the value of the specified key. If the key does not exist the special value 'nil' is returned. If the value stored at key is not a string an error is returned because GET can only handle string values."

For binary jedis, if the key does not exist, will the returned byte array contain byte representation of String "nil", or will the byte array be empty? Its not very clear from the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the key does not exist, `get` operation of both BinaryJedis and BinaryJedisCluster returns **`(byte[]) null`**.

Comment: Yes. Just verified it by running it locally.